# How to use Left join?

Tags: mysql, sql

i get an error got when i put this is my phpmyadmin sql,
error code #1052.

```
SELECT *
  FROM users u
  LEFT 
  JOIN user_tokens t
    ON u.userid = u.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN jt_campings_users cu 
    ON cu.userid = u.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN campings c
    ON c.user_id = u.id
 WHERE id = 9271
```

Comment: maybe id is ambiguous on your where clause. Try like: WHERE users.id = 9271

Comment: What does error code #1052 mean?

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`. Always name and qualify the columns you actually want returned. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Qualify *all* column names!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to give query hint to optimizer to where `id` is coming from because that might be possibility `id` is available in one or more tables :

```
WHERE u.id = 9271
```

So, the best practise to avoid such error is to use *alias* :

```
SELECT <column list> -- Do not use `*`, always qualify column list
FROM `users` u LEFT JOIN -- i removed LEFT JOIN user_tokens t as no mapping available 
     `jt_campings_users` jt 
      ON jt.userid = u.id LEFT JOIN
     `campings` c 
      ON c.user_id = users.id
WHERE u.id = 9271;
```

Comment: i tried this one but it gave back:  " unknowm column 'ut.userid' in on clause"

Comment: @emma. .  That `user_tokens` should be excluded, because you neither used that table in `ON` clause.

Comment: maybe usefull to add: it has to be a delte function but i tried this first to see if it works

Comment: @emma. .  Then mapping is also important.